# Как описать пространство имен в xml документации библиотеки классов

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sandcastle

Создаю документацию к своей библиотеке с помощью инструмента `Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI`. Все методы, свойства и т.д. описал с помощью XML комментариев документа. Но вот одну сущность незнаю как описать, это само пространство имен, не могу найти где его и как описать, прошу помощи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В неймспейсе заводится пустой класс с именем NamespaceDoc, его XML-документация считается документацией на постранство имён.
Также на этот класс ставится атрибут `[CompilerGenerated]`, чтобы он сам не попал в документацию.

```
namespace Some.Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Some.Test"/> namespace contains classes for ....
    /// </summary>
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGenerated]
    class NamespaceDoc
    {
    }
}
```

http://shfb.codeplex.com/workitem/15516

Если же вы используете Sandcastle Help File Builder, то у него в менюшках есть диалог для задания описаний неймспейсов.